# Can i use the new AMD Beta Driver for my APU?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics

as many of you know AMD has not proprietary Drivers for AMD in Ubuntu 16.04 but there is an AMD beta driver but apparently my card isn't supported yet.

i cant return to 14.04 because the proprietary driver (since the middle of this week) stopped working, the OS didn't allow me to reach the desktop unless i uninstall it, it happened to me on Ubuntu, Ubuntu-Gnome and Elementary OS

I have an A10 8700P processor with R6 Graphics (integrated)

i have dual boot with Windows 10, both of them x64

Thanks!

Comment: Do the open source drivers not work as provided in 16.04?

Comment: they work but not for steam, also, i used to get lower temperatures in elementary using the proprietary ones

Comment: The reason steam doesn't work isn't because of the video drivers really. It's because of steam.  See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam#Using_native_runtime for how to "fix" it. I had to do this for Steam after installing an R9 Nano. The new proprietary drivers wouldn't change this.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about lower temperatures exactly, but under normal usage, my R9 Nano card stays around 41C, as reported by sensors. My CPU and system temp are a bit higher than when I was using just the Intel CPU, but not much, and it was expected, since I installed a discrete card.

Comment: Hi dobey, thanks for the feedback. by  lower temperatures i was meaning temp between 48 and 56 on idle (the ones i used to get in EOS with the propietary drivers) but im getting now some similar temperatures so it's not a big deal right now.

Btw, the steam workaround should be done everytime i open it or just the first time?

Comment: The environment variable must be set whenever steam is run.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx the driver only supports some of the R9 chipsets, and the new RX 480.

Therefore, these drivers will not work for your card.

Comment: I already check the page and you are right, but some people were commenting that it worked with other AMD graphic cards (none of the APU's)